# Select, Modify and Insert result as new record in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

How can I force laravel to always create new record when I use save() method or use separated calls like `create` or `update`.
for example, I want to get some records from a table, modify them and save them as new records.

```
$products = Product::where('category_id', 10)->get();

foreach( $products as $product ){
    $product->name = 'new name';
    $product->save();
}
```

above script, update records, in `phalconphp` I can be specific and say `$product->create()` and new record will create.

Is this possible in Laravel?

Comment: It 'not very clear what do you mean by "modify them and save them as new records". You need to update existing records and insert also at the same time?

Comment: i think he dont want to update the record, just modify the result and save as another record,... am i right?

Comment: @Cedie Yes. that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach for cloning a model using `replicate`:

```
$products = Product::where('category_id', 10)->get();

foreach( $products as $product )
{
    // Clone the model
    $clone = $product->replicate();

    // Apply any changes you want to the cloned model
    $clone->name = 'new name';
    // ...

    // Save the cloned/modified model as a different record
    $clone->save();
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks , this is the way I was looking for. I don't know why there is no mention to replicate() in documentation ...

Answer (score 1):

why not...

```
$products = Product::where('category_id', 10)->get();

foreach( $products as $product ){
    $new_product = new Product();
    $new_product->name = 'new name';
    $new_product->other_column = $product->other_column;
    $new_product->save();
}
```

Comment: My products table has 30 columns, and I only want to edit 1 or two columns of them, this is not the best way. I think.

Comment: @Cedie Or you could for simplicity use; Product::create($product->toArray()) and if the fillable attributes on your model have been set it will sort everything out itself.

Comment: @Pars ahh, i see :) sorry

Comment: @MattBurrow ahh yes, he can do that also

Comment: well, I think ( not sure ) laravel doesn't have $record->create() to always insert new record. +1 for `phalconphp`

Comment: @Pars It has a static method create on the Eloquent model so it does have it... i.e. Product::create()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like the following? Create a new product and either you set its attributes from an existing one or assign a new value.

```
 $products = Product::where('category_id', 10)->get();

 foreach( $products as $product ){       

 $newproduct = new Product;
 $newproduct ->name = $product->name;  // or assign a new value
 $newproduct ->attribute1 = $product->attribute1; // or assign a new value
 $newproduct ->attribute2 = $product->attribute2;// or assign a new value
 $newproduct ->attribute3 = $product->attribute3;// or assign a new value
 $newproduct ->save();
 }
```